# How to Redirect New Domain to a different Sub Domain?

Tags: web, dns

I have a Subdomain `sub.yy1.com`  and I have a new domain `xx2.com` and I would like to redirect this new domain `xx2.com` to the subdomain `sub.yy1.com`  so, visitors will have to remember only the new domain `xx2.com` to visit the subdomain.

Can anyone help me to do this via htaccess. ? because most tutorials are about redirecting the same domain to the sub which is not what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying so far?  Maybe something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.:]+\.)*xx2\.com\.?(:[0-9]*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://sub\.yy1\.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Oh does this work? because I thought it only works for the same domain. Let me try it.

Comment: Yea I think as long as you fully qualify it, any URI should work.